# how to change vim default description?

Tags: vim

I would like to ask how to change the description in Vim when creating a file, where is the file that is responsible for this?

[image]

I'm using windows 10

Comment: This doesn't happen with Vim out of the box. Check your `.vimrc` for plugins etc. that might add this.

Comment: I completely forgot, I have clang_complete installed and most likely it does it, thank you very much for the hint!

Comment: Check this [link](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/vi-and-vim-autocommand-3-steps-to-add-custom-header-to-your-file/) @Cytorak 87